# Is it possible to automatically generate a Unix millisecond timestamp in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, timestamp, default-value

I have created a `created_time` field with `BIGINT` in a MySQL 5.7 table, now I want to auto generate a Unix millisecond timestamp when I insert a record. Is it possible to do this? I have tried the code below but it failed:

```
ALTER TABLE db.video_info MODIFY COLUMN created_time bigint(20) 
  DEFAULT (ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000)) NULL;
```

Comment: tip for questions, replace 'tried this but failed' and replace with 'tried this... which generated the error message....'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 supports the expression default like you show.

MySQL 5.7 does not support expressions as default. Only NULL, or a constant value, or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if it's a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column.

For MySQL 5.7, you have two alternatives:

- Declare the column as `created_time datetime(3) default current_timestamp(3)`.
- Use BIGINT as you are doing, but write a trigger to set the value.

Comment: ref: [documentation on data type defaults](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html)